# Symfony can't connect to azure-sql-edge Db on mac

Tags: php, symfony, azure-sql-edge

I've been trying to create a database with `php bin/console doctrine:database:create all day`
despite many attempts, I am asking for help in determining the correctly working connect string

this is what my connectString looks like: `DATABASE_URL="mysql://sa:hitman33@127.0.0.1:1433/Db?serverVersion=5.7.40"`

1433 - is a port that is the Azure sql port after command to create db i got

Unfortunately, after entering the database creation command again, I do not get the message at all :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rrma.png)